# Avoid filling up netmap tx buffer on link failure

Tags: c, network-programming, freebsd

I'm currently using netmap to send and receive packets. It's working like a charm, but there is one thing causing me problems.

When I pull out the network cable, netmap is filling up the available slots in the tx ring. When I reconnect the cable, all the old packets are immediately transmitted. I don't want that to happen.

Is there any way to avoid the old packets from being sent?

I'm programming in C and the program is running on FreeBSD.

Comment: don't put the packets in the buffer if you don't want to send them?

Comment: Well, any good ideas how to detect a link failure? Anyways, let me rephrase the question.

Is there any way to overwrite the packets I put in the buffer after a NIOCTXSYNC call?

Comment: don't know. maybe you could try overwriting them with invalid packets, so when they get transmitted it sends an invalid packet? I wouldn't try overwriting more than one piece of data (e.g. overwriting the whole packet with a new one) because of the obvious race condition.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.